# How do I solve the errors that Im getting?

Tags: java, methods

It is giving me an error on line where my system print line is.

It says:

> '.class' expected twice, ; expected and illegal start of expression

```
 class philip {

    public static void main (String[] args){

        System.out.println(total(int 3, int 4));
    }

    public static int total(){
        int x;
        int y;
        return x+y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To call a method, you don't specify the types inline at the caller. Also, you need to match the parameters. You need to change it to something like,

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    System.out.println(total(3, 4));
}

public static int total(int x, int y){ // <-- signature of two int parameters
    return x+y;
}
```

Another way to write `total` (using Java 8+) and *varargs* might look like

```
public static int total(int... arr) {
    return IntStream.of(arr).sum();
}
```

Which has the advantage that you can call `total(1, 2, 3)` or any number of parameters.

Answer (score 2):

A couple mistakes about how you are trying to call the method...

you mean:

```
public static void main (String[] args){
     System.out.println(total(3, 4));
}

public static int total(int x, int y){
     return x+y;
}
```